# Stored Procedures for non entity objects with ef core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a .net 6 ef core 6.0.7 project.

I need to call a stored procedure that return a DTO that has no equivalent object in database to call it on a DbSet.

I found some articles saying about SqlQuery or ExecuteRawSql that are both called from DbContext.Database but I can't connect the dots.

```
    public class ProcedureRepository
    {
        private DatabaseContext databaseContext;

        public ProcedureRepository(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
        {
            this.databaseContext = databaseContext;
        }

        public Task<OrderDTO> GetOrders()
        {
            databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand<OrderDTO>();
            databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<OrderDTO>();

            /both line throw error saying:
            /"DatabaseFacade does not containt a definition for ..." 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools- it connects the dots for you